# Manipulação de arquivos XML em C# - Dicas de bibliotecas

Tags: c#, xml, dll, library

Preciso fazer a manipulação de um arquivo XML em C#. É a primeira vez que vou fazer isso, e queria umas dicas. Meu algoritmo basicamente é esse:

1. **Preencher um XML a partir dos dados do meu sistema (Dados do DB).**

   Ex: Possuo uma entidade da qual vem meus dados exemplo Pessoa, que a mesma por 
   sua vez tem seus atributos.

   *Preciso pegar esses dados da Pessoa, e montar um xml.*
2. **Ler esse arquivo XML gerado, para execução de um algoritmo X, que 
   executará cálculos com base nos dados do meu XML.**

   *Esse algoritmo irá me fornecer novos dados, como resultados do meu estudo.*
3. **Após a execução do algoritmo X, gerar um XML com os resultados obtidos, a partir do algoritmo X.**

***Preciso de dicas sobre:***

Em suma o que desejo é:

- Gerar um xml com os dados de minha entidade,
- ler esse arquivo populando uma entidade de resultados.
- Exportar meu resultado para xml.

**Minha questão é:**

1 - Qual Lib posso usar para manipular esses arquivos? Isso é, existe uma biblioteca que possa usar para me ajudar a manipular arquivos xml em C#. O que quero dizer é, para não ter que fazer tudo na mão?

2 - Alguém tem um exemplo que possa me fornecer, ou alguma dica em como posso realizar essa tarefa?

**3 - Lib para automatizar essa tarefa?**

Grato.

Comment: é muito ampla a sua questão, porque não coloca um cenário que ai em cima disso possa solucionar a maioria das suas duvidas!

Comment: Acho que podes começar a pesquisar por Entity Framework, para fazer a modelação da tua BD em objectos C#. A partir daí, pesquisa por Linq to XML (permite que cries, alteres, ficheiros xml).

Comment: @RenatoAfonso Obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O C# disponibiliza algumas classes (*XmlSerializer, StreamWriter, StreamReader, etc...*) dos *namespaces* `System.Xml` e `System.IO` que você pode utilizar para manipular arquivos e fazer serialização XML.

Caso você não encontre uma Lib para automatizar, segue um exemplo abaixo:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Gerar um xml com os dados de minha entidade

        var pessoa = new Pessoa { Id = 1, Nome = "Renan" };

        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Pessoa));
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter("pessoa.xml");

        xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, pessoa);

        streamWriter.Close();

        // ler esse arquivopopulando uma entidade de resultados.
        // Exportar meu resultado para xml.

        FileStream meuFileStream = new FileStream("pessoa.xml", FileMode.Open);

        Pessoa _pessoa = (Pessoa)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(meuFileStream);

        Console.WriteLine(_pessoa.Nome); // Imprime "Renan"
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Pessoa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Xml gerado e gravado no arquivo "...\bin\Debug\pessoa.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Pessoa xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Nome>Renan</Nome>
</Pessoa>
```

Comment: Grato por sua ajuda.